# bootstrap grid system : how to remove gap between two columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap grid to have the responsive layout.

But I am unable to remove gap between two columns.
my code is as follows:

```
      <div class="contact-us-box"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <p class="contact-us-footer">Choose Share&Care as your development partner </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <a class="contact-us-link" href="../contact-us.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact Now!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my output is:

[image: screenshot]

I want to remove the gap between partner and contact now button.

please help me is this regard.

## My Solution

here is my solution:

```
<div class="contact-us-box"> 
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 contact-us-gap-p">
                    <p class="contact-us-footer">Choose Share&Care as your development partner </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 contact-us-gap-a">
                    <a class="contact-us-link" href="contact-us.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact Now!
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my css file :

```
.contact-us-gap-p{
   text-align: right;
}
.contact-us-gap-a{
    text-align: left;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .contact-us-gap-p{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .contact-us-gap-a{
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

This code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used css inline for semplicity, but using class is better. I simply aligned the text of the two div to reduce the gap between the two columns.

```
  <div style="text-align: right;" class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-center">
                   ...
   </div>

  <div style="text-align: left;" class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
```

If you do not want this to apply in mobile version, insert this code into media query for screen only
                 ....